# Movie about alien coming through a TV set

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Since I saw this in Goulburn in the 70s I've been looking for it, it's a 60s or 70s UK TV movie short movie.

The plot goes like this: an alien man was talking to a young girl in the family TV set, the cat got lost in the TV set, the brother got tied up by a rope that came out of the TV set, then the girl got the Alien man to come out of the TV and held his hand while the shocked parents looked on. The alien guy would talk to the girl when no one else was around.

I'd really appreciate any help, I just have to see it again.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the movie *Poltergeist*, but that movie has nothing to do with aliens.

Comment: @WadCheber I disagree with "a lot" given the cat was a bird and it did not get sucked in the TV set, the brother was hauled through a window by a tree, the girl never got any entity to come out of the TV & hold her hand. The only parts that seem to fit are the TV being the focus point/portal, and 'scary stuff happened'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Someone tied up - yes, by braces.  Brother grabbed - yes, by a tree.  Rope through a portal of some kind - yes, the mother and daughter.  Someone talking to the girl through the TV when no one else is around - yes.  Girl with hands on/near TV - [yes](http://www.halloweenforevermore.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Poltergeist-Movie.jpg)  My point?  If you jumble some elements and misremember others, it sounds like Poltergeist.

Comment: The girl's name was Susan. I saw that movie in the 70's but don't know the name.

Comment: I have also seen this movie! I remember it was shot like a soap opera (probably​ on tape). It was a really cheesy production, nothing like Poltergeist. The brother (or was it a cousin?) has a history with the alien. He hears the girl talk about this person and he threatens to expose him. I remember the alien gets angry and it shows him in reverse video. The relative tries to tell the girl how the alien also killed his pet many years ago. For whatever reason he ceases talking to the alien and abandons the TV in the attic. Unfortunately I don't remember the title either.

Answer (score 3):

"Alien Lover"(ABC Wide World of Mystery 1973-1975)

This WAS shot on videotape as one of the commentators wrote and was a feature length episode of this early '70s anthology series, and the main character WAS named Susan. Here is the plot synopsis from IMDB.

"An orphaned teenager becomes involved with an alien who was beamed to Earth from another galaxy in a TV signal. Is the alien a dream come true or a harbinger of doom?"

. . . and here is the entire movie from YouTube.

Comment: my goodness, it looks like @john has his answer!

Comment: Thank you PhasedOut. I'm glad I got at least 1 vote because this is pretty obscure. I found this when I was searching for an answer for  MY question which is posted on here and haven't been able to find yet.

Answer (score -1):

The Ring, on an island, girl thrown down a well, d there. A videotape made, anyone who watches it dies, murdered by a ghost of the girl, who climbs out of a well, and comes through the tv screen.

Comment: Ghosts are not the same as aliens, this doesn't answer the question.