# Name of old Sci-fi movie where alien communicates and deceives woman through the TV screen static?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

When I was a kid (early 80s) I barely remember watching a movie on TV about an alien who masqueraded as a benevolent humanoid and communicated with a woman through television screen static.  The movie ended with the alien tricking the woman, and if my memory is right, somehow kidnapping her through the TV.  (I know it sounds like Poltergeist, but is was a few years before that).

Sorry if the specifics aren't clear or accurate... but it has been driving me crazy for years that I don't know what the movie was called! It did really freak me out at the time.

Any suggestions would be so awesome. Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Possibly the same movie? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126739/movie-about-alien-coming-through-a-tv-set alas with no answer.

Comment: Hi everyone. Mystery solved! TV movie made in 1975 titled: "Alien Lover" The full movie is on Youtube. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie about alien coming through a TV set](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126739/movie-about-alien-coming-through-a-tv-set)

Comment: @Machavity - That question doesn't have an accepted answer, hence we can't close them as dupes of each other.

Comment: @theguest -  You solved it on [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126739/movie-about-alien-coming-through-a-tv-set?noredirect=1&lq=1), not this one.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open for the reason @Valorum cited above.

Comment: @Valorum. Ok, thank you. I see it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Alien Lover](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072465/) from 1975, part of the Wide World of Mystery anthology series of films.

> An orphaned teenager becomes involved with an alien who was beamed to
>   Earth from another galaxy in a TV signal. Is the alien a dream come
>   true or a harbinger of doom?