# 70s or 80s B-movie about aliens in a family's television, fry the house cat and trap the son inside the TV

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion, b-movies

I saw this B-grade movie in the late 1970s or early 1980s about human looking aliens from another dimension who try to get to our dimension via a family's TV set.

The aliens tried bringing the family cat through and it got fried. At the end, the aliens succeed in bringing the family's son into their dimension and it ends with the son inside the television yelling for help.

Comment: While it's not a movie, this sounds similar to the Twilight Zone episode ["Little Girl Lost"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Girl_Lost_(The_Twilight_Zone))

Comment: @BruceWayne, OMG! TZ totally ripped off the Simpsons! S07E06 ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Alien Lover* (1975)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072465/):

> An orphaned teenager becomes involved with an alien who was beamed to Earth from another galaxy in a TV signal. Is the alien a dream come true or a harbinger of doom?

The movie is on YouTube (see below), relevant timestamps:

- 35'45, curious cat; fried cat at 38'52;
- 1'04'10, the trapped-in-TV son screaming "Motheeeeer" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6QQD.jpg));

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] aliens television is:q` which returned, among others, [Name of old Sci-fi movie where alien communicates and deceives woman through the TV screen static?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162729/) to which *Alien Lover* was suggested as an answer. Another question, [Movie about alien coming through a TV set](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/126739/), suggests the cat was featured too:

> The plot goes like this: an alien man was talking to a young girl in the family TV set, **the cat got lost in the TV set**, the brother got tied up by a rope that came out of the TV set, then the girl got the Alien man to come out of the TV and held his hand while the shocked parents looked on. The alien guy would talk to the girl when no one else was around.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks Jenayah,that's it! Ive been looking for the title for years.

Comment: @KSB you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! :)